# Git start branch from another branch without tracking

Tags: git

I want to create a branch `foo` (and have it checked out) that'll start on the same commit as `origin/bar`, but I don't currently have `origin/bar` checked out. Is there a one-liner that does this?

Comment: Technically you *can't* have `origin/bar` checked out as it's not a (regular, local) branch.  You can check out the commit to which the remote-tracking branch points.  Generally you want `--no-track` as hvd already answered, though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it in a single command: `git checkout` allows `git branch`'s `--no-track` option to be specified directly.

```
git checkout -b foo --no-track origin/bar
```

Comment: Can somebody explain this in a little more detail? How is this different than `--track` ?

Comment: Great answer. For the sake of readability, I would use different order (personal preference):

    `git checkout -b foo origin/bar --no-track`

Or with the switch

    `git switch -c foo origin/bar --no-track`

Answer (score 2):

It depends whether you want your new branch to track the remote `origin/bar`.

To track the remote:

```
git checkout -b foo origin/bar
```

To not track the remote:

```
git checkout -b foo --no-track origin/bar
```

(You can always add a tracking relationship later.)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
git branch foo origin/bar
git checkout foo
```

And if you insist on oneline:

```
git checkout -b foo origin/bar
```

Answer (score -1):

Git has a flag for creating such a branch:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout/

> ***`--orphan`***
>   Create a new orphan branch, named , started from  and switch to it. The first commit made on this new branch will have no parents and it will be the root of a new history totally disconnected from all the other branches and commits.
>
> The index and the working tree are adjusted as if you had previously run `git checkout <start_point>`.
>
> **This allows you to start a new history** that records a set of paths similar to  by easily running `git commit -a` to make the root commit.
>
> This can be useful when you want to publish the tree from a commit without exposing its full history. You might want to do this to publish an open source branch of a project whose current tree is `clean`, but whose full history contains proprietary or otherwise encumbered bits of code.
>
> If you want to start a disconnected history that records a set of paths that is totally different from the one of , then you should clear the index and the working tree right after creating the orphan branch by running `git rm -rf .` from the top level of the working tree. Afterwards you will be ready to prepare your new files, repopulating the working tree, by copying them from elsewhere, extracting a tarball, etc.

Comment: This doesn't seem like what the OP asked for. I don't see any mention in the question of disconnecting history, they just want to branch from an existing branch without bothering to check it out first.

Comment: I agree, reading the question again, i first understood that he wants branch without history :-)